# creating nested hashmap from text file: not all data stored, may be over written

Tags: java, hashmap, overwrite

I need to read two files, add them to a hashmap and make a comparison. It's a large file to do it manually. Here is my Java code :

```
 /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("comparetheresults/595231gov_nov_13_assessed.txt"));
        BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("comparetheresults/627231farsidetect.txt"));

          HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> hmap1 = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>();
          HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> hmap2 = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>();
          ArrayList<String>  rel= new ArrayList<String>();
          String Id = null;


         String line = null;
         String relation = null;
         while ((line = in1.readLine()) != null){
             if(line.contains("ID:")){
                 hmap1.put(line, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>());
                 Id = line;
             }
             else if(line.contains("Relation:")){
                 relation = line;
             }
             else if(line.contains("Result:")){
                 if(rel == null)
                    rel= new ArrayList<>();
                 rel.add(line);
                 hmap1.get(Id).put(relation, rel);
             }
             else if(line.contains("TP") || line.contains("FP") || line.contains("TN") || line.contains("FN")){
                 rel.add(line);
                 hmap1.get(Id).put(relation, rel); 
                 rel = null;
             }

         }

        for (Object e : hmap1.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        System.out.println();



        in1.close();
        in2.close();
    }

}
```

### Here's the format of The File that is read

> ID: 01 
>  Sentence: blah blah blah 
>  Relation: blah blah 
>   Result: abc 
>  TN
>
> ID: 01 
>  Sentence: blah blah blah 
>  Relation: blah blah 
>   Result: xyz 
>  FP
>
> ID: 02 
>  Sentence: blah blah blah 
>  Relation: blah blah 
>   Result: blah blah 
>  FP

The problem, is that I can see only one entry of each ID in the result. Other data may be over-written. Is there something wrong I did, in the hashmap format?

Help please.

Thanks.

Comment: A `HashMap` can contain only one object per key, so only the last value encountered for each key is stored; each time you add a new value with the same key it replaces the previous one.  If you need multiple values for each key you need to use a [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html), or a `Map<String,List<String>>` and manage the list value yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a file where the same ID exists multiple times, and you're not properly handling the fact that this could be the case.

You check to see if the `Result:` entry is in the map, and add the result to the ArrayList stored at the key specified in `Relation:` but you don't check to see if the ID already exists in the map before creating a new HashMap.

This line is what's overwriting your data for each ID

```
if(line.contains("ID:")){
     hmap1.put(line, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>());
     Id = line;
}
```

If the line contains `ID:` you create a new HashMap at whatever key is defined in `ID:`, even if there already exists one.

If you want to add to the data already stored in this key, you need to do the same thing you're doing with the logic for `Result:`

```
if(line.contains("ID:")){
    if ( hmap1.containsKey(line) ) {
        // get the entry and do something with it
    }
    else { 
        hmap1.put(line, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>());
    }
    Id = line;
}
```

Also, it seems you have a small issue with the processing of the `Result:` field in that you're doing something odd with the ArrayList to store the results. The way it's coded, it doesn't seem like what you want. Suppose you have a result, and you add it to a new list, and then later you want to add something else to the list of result, you never get the list out of the HashMap to add it, you just make a new ArrayList each time.

Try this instead:

```
else if(line.contains("Result:")){
    // check if the key exists in the map, or if the value is null
    if( !hmap1.get(Id).containsKey(relation) || hmap1.get(Id).get(relation) == null ) {
        rel = new ArrayList<>(); // make new list
    }
    // otherwise, get the list from your map
    else {
        rel = hmap1.get(Id).get(relation); // get the result list
    }
    // add result to the list
    rel.add(line); 
    // add the list to the map...
    hmap1.get(Id).put(relation, rel);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the same ID, I need to add different relations and for each relation there would be a list containing the 2 values/strings as results. Will this do the job?

Comment: It will certainly get you started. I didn't know what you wanted to do, so I didn't fill in any implementation details. If you don't overwrite your ID with a new hashmap without checking first that it exists, you can get the value for that ID later and do what you need. From looking at your code, it looks like it should work, minus a little bit of debugging to make sure...

Comment: Thank You @Ryan J. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: There is one problem I noticed with the result processing that could hang you up, and I'll update the answer to call it out

Comment: Thank You @Ryan It worked !! I just modified the code as 
             if(line.contains("ID:")){
                 if(!hmap1.containsKey(line))
                    hmap1.put(line, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>());
                 Id = line;
             }

and it fixed the problem I would give you you an upvote if I had enough reputation to vote on answers!

Comment: If my answer was satisfactory, do me a favor and mark it as accepted. Glad it helped you out.